# Codeigniter Query to display upcoming future date first in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I am trying to display data on table. but in that table data should be display in following orders
1. upcoming Future dates Ascending order from current date
2.Past dates

example - Today date 2017-04-24
Result as : 
1  2017-04-26
            2  2017-04-28
            3  2017-05-03
            4  2017-08-24 
            5  2016-06-26

My Query is -

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('dnms_domains');
    $this->db->where('is_status',0);
    $this->db->order_by('IF(expiry_date <=DATE(NOW()), 0, 1), expiry_date DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //echo($this->db->last_query());
        //exit;     
    return $query->result();
```

But i didn't get expected result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working query, tested and confirmed:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select *, DATEDIFF(expiry_date, CURRENT_DATE) as diff, 
    DATEDIFF(expiry_date, CURRENT_DATE) >= 0 as di 
    from dmns_domains order by di desc, 
    case when di = 1 then -1 * diff 
         else diff
    end desc');

return $query->result();
```

Indented the code for readability, you may have to make it one line to execute.

**Explanation**: Added two extra columns:

- the day differences between the current date and the column value,
- if the column value is greater than the current date

then sorted the values using these indicators.

Comment: i tried your code. it is running in direct mysql like (SELECT * FROM dnms_domains WHERE expiry_date >=DATE(NOW()) AND is_status = 0 ORDER BY expiry_date ASC) UNION (SELECT * FROM dnms_domains WHERE expiry_date < DATE(NOW()) AND is_status = 0 ORDER BY expiry_date DESC)    when i used in codeigniter i am getting "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY" error

Comment: tried this too. getting error like - Error Number: 1096

No tables used  

SELECT *

Comment: did you try it by specific columns instead of "SELECT *" ?

Comment: Are you using `->get()` to get the results?

Comment: Try without get.

Comment: when i'm using union then the date got collapsed. i have shown in the image. i am not getting in order

Comment: This query should give you the correct result. Do you have any other filters set on phpmyadmin?

Comment: while running individually . i am getting correct result. while using union that time it is getting collapsed

Comment: Will it be too expensive to run seperate queries then for your page?

Comment: can you try the second approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142457/discussion-between-karthick-anbazhagan-and-taha-paksu).

Comment: Updated with a tested query.